# How to add item into NSOutlineView in the edit mode?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

I am working with `NSOutlineView`, and everything works well, I can enter edit mode when clicking on the table cell.

However, I want to enter the edit mode automatically when a new row is inserted.

I played around with `makeFirstResponder` method, but it doesn't work.

Here is what I did:

```
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  viewForTableColumn:tableColumn:item
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        var result = outlineView.make(withIdentifier: tableColumn?.identifier ?? "", owner: self)

        if let node = (item as! NSTreeNode).representedObject as? BaseNode {
            if self.outlineView(outlineView, isGroupItem: item) {    // is it a special group (not a folder)?
                // Group items are sections of our outline that can be hidden/shown (i.e. PLACES/BOOKMARKS).
                let identifier = outlineView.tableColumns[0].identifier

                result = outlineView.make(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView?
                let value = node.nodeTitle
                (result as! NSTableCellView).textField!.stringValue = value
            } else if node.isSeparator {
                result = outlineView.make(withIdentifier: "SeparatorView", owner: self)
            } else {
                (result as! NSTableCellView).textField!.stringValue = node.nodeTitle
                (result as! NSTableCellView).imageView!.image = node.nodeIcon
                if node.isLeaf {
                     let textField = (result as! NSTableCellView).textField!
                     (result as! NSTableCellView).window?.makeFirstResponder(textField)
                    textField.isEditable = true // make leaf title's editable.
                    //### Translator's extra
                    textField.target = self
                    textField.action = #selector(self.didEditTextField(_:))
                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't showing all relevant lines of code.  Nobody even knows your data source.

Comment: @ElTomato, what can be wrong with the data? It's pretty huge class, it implements NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource also I am using NSTreeController. I just want to understand what is the usual way to implement this in Swift. Thanks.

Comment: You can't enter the edit mode automatically when a new row is inserted, you have to do some coding. How do you insert a new row?

Comment: @Willeke, this is why I am asking : ) The node is inserted via `NSTreeController`. `self.treeController.insert(node, atArrangedObjectIndexPath: indexPath)`. And then I am returning the view used to display the specified item and column from the method above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `self.treeController.insert(node, atArrangedObjectIndexPath: indexPath)` you can start edit with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    let node = self.treeController.arrangedObjects.descendant(at: indexPath)
    let row = self.outlineView.row(forItem: node)
    let view = self.outlineView.view(atColumn: 0, row: row, makeIfNecessary: false)
    if let cellView = view as? NSTableCellView {
        if let textField = cellView.textField {
            if textField.acceptsFirstResponder {
                self.window.makeFirstResponder(textField)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your answer

Comment: So it seems `textField.acceptsFirstResponder` is always false in my case...

Comment: Ok I added your code to the method I wrote above, and it works! But after `self.treeController.insert` it doesn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: `acceptsFirstResponder` is false if the text field is not editable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Willeke!